# facebook api in R: OAuthException error, code 803

Tags: facebook, r, api

Im trying to connect to Facebook using R. I tried to use the codes from

https://github.com/datamgmt/facebook-data-mining

Which gets the user information with the following code:

```
access.token<- "AAACE________n6bcITRIMCZCKhMySOV" #my access token
FacebookFetch <- function(access.path = "me", access.token, access.options) {
      if (missing(access.options)) {
        access.options <- ""
      }
      else {
        access.options <- sprintf("?%s", paste(names(access.options), "=", 
                                               unlist(access.options), collapse = "&", sep = ""))
      }
      data <- getURL(sprintf("https://graph.facebook.com/%s%s&access_token=%s", 
                             access.path, access.options, access.token),cainfo="cacert.pem")
      fromJSON(data)
    }

individual.id <- "100__72"  # my ID

individual <- FacebookFetch(access.path=paste(individual.id),access.token=access.token )
if (length(individual$id)) {
  cat ("Working with individual: ",individual$name," (",individual$id,")\n", sep="")
} else{
  cat("Message: ", unlist(individual)[1], "\n")
  cat("Type:    ", unlist(individual)[2], "\n")
  cat("Code:    ", unlist(individual)[3], "\n")
  stop("   Cannot continue")
}

where cainfo="cacert.pem" is added to work around the SSL certificate verification error.
```

Although now I get the following error and I have no idea how to solve this.

```
Message:  (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: 100__72&access_token=AAACE________n6bcITRIMCZCKhMySOV 
Type:     OAuthException 
Code:     803
```

I found some posts where people got the same problem, only not using R but other programs, the problem was fixed by making the token and id a character. However, in R, these are already of class character.

When im recreating the url in the browser it returns the same error, while the graph explorer returns all the correct information. I have tried to refresh the token multiple times, but that didn't work. 
The API reference book doesn't state what error code 803 entails.

does anybody have an idea how to solve this?
Im using r 2.15.2 in Rstudio on a windows 7 pro (also tried it on windows vista)

Comment: after the update of R, it all works fine! Don't know why